# Imports not working in Jest that start with @

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I recently joined a team of developers to work on their webapp.
I am writing tests for it and most of their files use `@ imports` instead of writing the filepath in the format of ../../

When trying to write tests in Jest for these I am unable to import and keep getting this error

```
Cannot find module '@util/helpers.js' from '_controller.js'
```

Is there a way I can configure jest to accept @ based imports?
I have looked long and hard online and so far have not been able to find any solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to module name mapper fixed it

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@util(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/util$1",
    }
```